# How do I access database information from a Rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to look at my index.html.erb file I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Products#index
undefined method `name' for #<Product:0x4a77de8>
```

Here is my code

Controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  .
  .
  .

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end
end
```

View:

```
<h1>List of products</h1>

<table>
<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= product.name %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= product.description %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= product.price %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

I thought the controller would gather all the entries I have inputted into the 'Product' table in the database and place them into the @products variable. After that I thought the view should iterate through the items in @products and call the name, description, price values for each product and output a table.

Where have I gone wrong here?

Any help appreciated thanks alot.

Comment: Is there a name column in `products` table? Did you forget to migrate the database?

Comment: Yeah, I have done this. I also can go into the console and type Product.name and it works.

Comment: can you try `Product.first.name` or `Product.last.name`

Comment: When I try `Product.first.name` it then says `undefined method 'first'`

Comment: can you please post your `product` model

Comment: Restart your server. Everything will be fine.

Comment: OMG, I just went to post my model and I have a column named `title` not `name`. Thanks for the help guys sorry for wasting your time :)